# Como esperar duas promessas antes de retornar a funçao?

Tags: javascript, react, react-native, promises

Estou fazendo um código que faz duas requisições, o valor retornardo é o tamanho de uma arquivo `content-length`, mas preciso que a função que contem essas duas requisições retorne o valor depois que as requisições finalizarem (Sim, elas demoram um pouco). Porém não estou sabendo lidar com essa espera de requisições.

Sendo mais detalhado, quando chamo a função: `addItem` o função `saveFiles` será chamada, dentro deste função será chamada mais duas funções (as vezes apenas uma dependendo do tipo de mídia) `_getImage` e `_getVideo`, essas duas funções irão fazer o download da mídia e salvar no celular e retornar o tamanho do arquivo. Pórem dentro de `saveFiles` as funções estão retornando antes mesmo de terminarem, assim não tenho o valor de size quando necessito.

Tentei usar o `async` e o `await`, mas não obtive sucesso, mesmo assim minhas funções não estão esperando. Existe alguma forma de esperar uma promessa terminar para depois executar o promisso passo?

```js
import RNFetchBlob from 'rn-fetch-blob';

export default class Manager {
  constructor(maxSize) {
    this.maxSize = maxSize;
    this.listOfFiles = [];
    this.dirs = RNFetchBlob.fs.dirs;
  }

  addItem(item, media) {
    size = this.saveFiles(item);
    console.log(size);
    this.listOfFiles.push({
      inFeed: false,
      media: media,
    })
  }

  seeFiles() {
    for(i = 0 ; i < this.listOfFiles.length; i++) {
      console.log(this.listOfFiles[i])
    }
  }

  saveFiles(item) {
    var sizeImage = 0;
    var sizeVideo = 0;

    if(item.type == 'Animated') {
      sizeVideo = this._getVideo(item.images.image460svwm.url);
      sizeImage = this._getImage(item.images.image460.url);
    } else {
      sizeImage = this._getImage(item.images.image460.url);
    }

    return sizeImage + sizeVideo;
  }

  async _getImage(url) {
    var filename = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
    return await RNFetchBlob.config({
      // add this option that makes response data to be stored as a file,
      // this is much more performant.
      fileCache : true,
      path : this.dirs.DocumentDir + '/media/' + filename
    })
    .fetch('GET', url, {
      //some headers ..
    })
    .then((res) => {
      console.log(res.respInfo.headers['content-length'])
      return res.respInfo.headers['content-length']
    })
  }

  async _getVideo(url) {
    var filename = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
    return await RNFetchBlob.config({
      // add this option that makes response data to be stored as a file,
      // this is much more performant.
      fileCache : true,
      path : this.dirs.DocumentDir + '/media/' + filename
    })
    .fetch('GET', url, {
      //some headers ..
    })
    .then((res) => {
      console.log(res.respInfo.headers['content-length'])
      return res.respInfo.headers['content-length']
    })
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Você deve ter em mente que tanto `_getImage` quanto `_getVideo` são funções que retornam `Promise`s. Logo, você deve aguardar a sua resolução a partir da função `saveFiles`. Como você deseja esperar que as **duas** promessas se resolvam, o meio mais simples de se fazer isso é usar [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all), que aguarda a resolução de todas as `Promise`s passadas.

Assim:

```
saveFiles(item) {
  // Inicializamos o `array` com as funções que desejamos que sejam executadas.
  const promises = [this._getImage(item.images.image460.url)];

  // Se o item for do `type` `'Animated'`, adicionamos mais um item à lista:
  if (item.type === 'Animated') {
    promises.push(this._getVideo(item.images.image460svwm.url));
  }

  // Aguardamos que todas as `Promise`s  sejam executadas:
  return Promise.all(promises).then(([sizeImage, sizeVideo]) => {
    return sizeImage + (sizeVideo || 0);
  });
}
```

A vantagem de usar o `Promise.all` é que ele executa todas as `Promise`s em paralelo, logo, o resultado será quase duas vezes mais rápido, já que uma não depende da outra. :)

Note que o método `saveFiles` ainda irá retornar uma `Promise`, logo, para obter o resultado, use o `then`. Você provavelmente irá querer fazer isso no `componentDidMount`:

```
componentDidMount() {
  //              ↓↓↓↓
  saveFiles(item).then((sumOfSizes) => {
    this.setState({ sumOfSizes })
  })
}
```

---

Você pode ainda combinar o `async`/`await` com o `Promise.all`, ficando com:

```
async saveFiles(item) {
  // Inicializamos o `array` com as funções que desejamos que sejam executadas.
  const promises = [this._getImage(item.images.image460.url)];

  // Se o item for do `type` `'Animated'`, adicionamos mais um item à lista:
  if (item.type === 'Animated') {
    promises.push(this._getVideo(item.images.image460svwm.url));
  }

  // Aguardamos que todas as `Promise`s  sejam executadas:
  const [sizeImage, sizeVideo] = await Promise.all(promises);

  // Retornamos a soma:
  return sizeImage + (sizeVideo || 0);
}

async componentDidMount() {
  const sumOfSizes = await saveFiles(item);
  this.setState({ sumOfSizes });
}
```

Comment: É importante salientar que: **Se qualquer uma das promessas passadas for rejeitada, a `Promise.all` rejeita assincronamente com o valor da promessa que foi rejeitado**

Answer (score 0):

o único jeito de esperar um Promise é usando o async/await se os teus métodos `_getVideo` e `_getImage` retornam uma Promise basta no seu método `saveFiles` fazer:

```
async saveFiles(item) {
    var sizeImage = 0;
    var sizeVideo = 0;

    if(item.type == 'Animated') {
        sizeVideo = await this._getVideo(item.images.image460svwm.url);
        sizeImage = await this._getImage(item.images.image460.url);
    } else {
        sizeImage = await this._getImage(item.images.image460.url);
    }

    return sizeImage + sizeVideo;
}
```

Eu também daria uma dica a você, para começar a usar let ou const ao invés de var: https://medium.com/collabcode/javascript-e-suas-vari%C3%A1veis-var-let-e-const-b035b44c2dab